# If else condition for check and uncheck checkbox in jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

[image]i have some filters applied to products .It has one section where i'm filtering products by clicking checkbox.I'm using jquery for this. Problem is when i try to uncheck checkbox it is showing same results as before and even if i uncheck it is still showing checked.I want to reset page if checkbox is unchecked.

see the image above i'm using checkbox for filtering products, if i click any checkbox, it is showing me some result, now i want to uncheck checkbox and rest the page. But if i try to uncheck it, it is still showing as checked

View code:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<?php

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {                           
?>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="<?= $tag->id ?>" name="tags[]" class="tags" <?= (isset($current_tags) && in_array($tag->id, $current_tags)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>><?= $tag->tag_name ?></label>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

jquery code:

```
$('.tags').change(function () {
    var current = $(this);
    var tags = [];
    $('.tags').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        tags.push($(this).val());
    }
    else {
        resetAll();
    }
    });
    window.location = '<?= current_url() . '?' . (($this->input->get_post('s')) ? 's=' . $this->input->get_post('s') . '&' : '') ?>tags=' + tags.join('-');
});
});
```

Controller code:

```
if ($this->input->get_post('tags')) {
    $this->data['current_tags'] = explode('-', $this->input->get_post('tags'));
    $filters['deals.tags'] = $this->data['current_tags'];
    $_SESSION['filters_counter'] += 1;      
}
```

Model code:

```
function get($filters = [], $sort_filters = [], $limit = 0, $offset = 0, $sort_filters_mobile = []) {

$this->db->select('deals.*,deals.expiry_date_time,categories.category_name,categories.seo_url as category_seo_url,sub_categories.sub_category_name,sub_categories.seo_url as sub_category_seo_url,stores.store_name,stores.is_direct_link');
$this->db->from('deals');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id=deals.categories_id');
$this->db->join('sub_categories', 'sub_categories.id=deals.sub_categories_id');
$this->db->join('stores', 'stores.id=deals.stores_id');
$this->db->where("deals.status", 1);
$this->db->where("stores.current_status", 'Active');
foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
    if ($key == 'deals.tags') {
        $cond = array();
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        $cond[] = 'FIND_IN_SET("' . $val . '",deals.tags) != 0';
        }
        $this->db->where('(' . implode(' OR ', $cond) . ')');
    } else {
        $key_array = explode(' ', $key);
        if (isset($key_array[1]) && ($key_array[1] == "!=")) {
        $this->db->where_not_in($key_array[0], $value);
        } else {
        $this->db->where_in($key, $value);
        }
    }
    } elseif ($key == 'deals.deal_title') {
    $this->db->like($key, $value);
    } elseif ($key == 'deals.tags') {
    $this->db->where('FIND_IN_SET("' . $value . '",deals.tags) !=', 0);
    } else {
    $this->db->where($key, $value);
    }
}
foreach ($sort_filters as $key => $value) {
    $this->db->order_by($key, $value);
}
if ($limit != 0) {
    if ($offset != 0) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    } else {
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    }
}
$data = $this->db->get()->result();
if ($data) {
    foreach ($data as $item) 
    if ($item->current_status == 'Active') {
        $item->current_status_bootstrap_class = 'primary';
    } else {
        $item->current_status_bootstrap_class = 'danger';
    }
    if ($item->deal_type == 'DEAL') {
       $item->deal_type_bootstrap_class = 'primary';
        $item->deal_type_text = 'Deal';
    } else {
        $item->deal_type_bootstrap_class = 'success';
        $item->deal_type_text = 'Offer & Coupon';
    }
    $item->image = FILE_UPLOADED_PATH . $item->image;
    }
    return $data;
}
return [];

}
```

I have tried adding else condition but it is not working.Please help!

Comment: Cant understand what you are trying to tell.. Please explain in detail.

Comment: @Thameem  i'm fetching checkbox values dynamically using mysql codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

**Cant get what you are trying to tell. But i hope you must get some idea from this**

```js
$('.tags').change(function () {
    var current = $(this);
    if($(current).prop('checked') == true){
        alert("checked");
    }
    else{
        alert("UN-checked");
        //You should reset your page here or whatever u mean
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="tags[]" class="tags" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="tags[]" class="tags" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="tags[]" class="tags" />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="tags[]" class="tags" />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="tags[]" class="tags" />
```

Comment: Thank you! . I tried adding else but condition is directly going to else without executing if